# Issue with MAX3140 UART when sending 64-bit frame using 16-bit frame configuration

Tags: spi, uart, modbus

I am facing an issue with the MAX3140 UART when attempting to send a 64-bit frame through a 16-bit frame configuration. The MAX3140 uses a 16-bit frame for communication, where the upper 8 bits are designated for configuration, and the lower 8 bits for data. To send a 64-bit frame, I have broken it down into 8 separate 8-bit bytes and attempted to send these bytes as 16-bit words through the UART.

Actual sending frame ={0x02,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0xC4,0x38}
modified frames  =
data_1[]={0x8002}
data_2[]={0x8003}
data_3[]={0x8000}
data_4[]={0x8000}
data_5[]={0x8000}
data_6[]={0x8002}
data_7[]={0x80C4}
data_8[]={0x8038}

However, the UART output I receive consists of 8-bit data chunks instead of the expected 16-bit words:

Actual outputs =

0x02
0x03
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x02
0xC4
0x38

Required out put=0x02 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0xC4 0x38

It seems like the UART output is not aligning the 8-bit bytes into 16-bit words as intended. I have double-checked the code and the logic, but I'm unable to identify the issue causing this behavior.

Could you please review the code and provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Both TX adn RX data registers seem to only have 8 bits for actual data, why do you think you would receive 16 bit data? see page 21 and 22 of the register description. So when you pass your 16 bit values its only using the lower 8 as data and that is what you would see at the other end. This is from a quick skim of the datasheet . 
Furthermore in your question, your actual output and required output are identical so I do not understand the issue?
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX3140.pdf

Comment: Currently, I receive 8 bits on the Tx line at a time, but our actual requirement is to receive 64 bits on the Tx line at a time. To achieve this, I sent 8 times by splitting my 64 bits of data. Now the problem is I received 8 bits of data 8 times on the Tx line. Can I store these 64 bits of data on the Tx buffer and transmit together? Because our Modbus sensor input frame should be 64 bits of data; it responds only in this state.